# SQL Server Itegration Service (SSIS) - How Can I Get the Package Error Message?

Tags: ssis

Does anybody help me?

I am running a Script Taks in my package for sending and receiving files using FtpClientConnection and for making some tests I am simulating possibles fails.

Edited:

When I run my Script Task in debug mode I have this error message: **"{"Exceção de HRESULT: 0xC001602A"}"** and this error code: **-1073651670**.

Looking for this error code on http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms345164.aspx I found "An error occurred in the requested FTP operation. Detailed error description: %1."

When my Script Task throw the error I have a different message: "The script returned a failure result".

But in my package error I have the same message given inside my Script Task: "Error: An error occurred in the requested FTP operation. Detailed error description: **The server name or address could not be resolved**."

How can I convert this error "Exceção de HRESULT: 0xC001602A" in that message given by my package?

Is that clear?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: For code related questions, please provide the code otherwise we're wasting each other's time

Comment: Turn on pacakage logging. Now you should have that error in a database. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I tried turn on package logging but just this message isn't save in a database or text file. I don't know why. I am editing my post with the error code returned inside my Script Task.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I found this code on internet but I DON'T KNOW WHY when I run it in debug mode I get this message: **"Exceção de HRESULT: 0xC001602A"** and in a SQL Job I get this:  **"An error occurred in the requested FTP operation. Detailed error description: The password was not allowed."**

SSIS is kinda crazy, but that's working...

Thanks...

```
catch (COMException ex)
{
    string symbolicName = GetSymbolicName(ex.ErrorCode);
    Console.WriteLine("Symbolic Name: {0}", symbolicName);
}

public static string GetSymbolicName(int errorCode)
{
    string symbolicName = string.Empty;
    HResults hresults = new HResults();

    foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in hresults.GetType().GetFields())
    {
        if ((int)fieldInfo.GetValue(hresults) == errorCode)
        {
            symbolicName = fieldInfo.Name;
            break;
        }
    }

    return symbolicName;
}
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2009/08/03/looking-up-ssis-hresult-comexception-errorcode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since this helped me out, I wanted to contribute back with a VB.Net version of the above C# :)

```
Catch ComEx as COMException
    Console.WriteLine("Symbolic Name: {0}", GetSymbolicName(ComEx.ErrorCode))
End Try

Public Shared Function GetSymbolicName(ByVal errorCode As Long) As String
    Dim symbolicName As String = String.Empty
    Dim hresults As HResults = New HResults
    Dim thisError As Integer = Int32.Parse(errorCode.ToString)

    For Each fieldInfo As FieldInfo In hresults.GetType().GetFields()
        If Int32.Parse(fieldInfo.GetValue(hresults).ToString) = thisError Then
            symbolicName = fieldInfo.Name
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Return symbolicName
End Function
```

Just a warning, I actually did the function call in two lines (per the C#) but I can't think of a reason not to do the Console.Writeline with the function call in one line.